# Propertional width with constant spaces in responsive design

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, responsive-design

I am having trouble coming out with a responsive component that scales some buttons with a proportional width, but with constant spaces.

In the example below, the small arrows are all 15px and I want the buttons to scale up or down depending on the max width of my box, but the spaces to stay constant.
I tried this property: `calc((100% / ${allEleemnts}) - (${spaces} / 2))`,

But I don't quite obtain the exact same space between all the elements when the page scales up or down.
I would really appreciate some feedback on my try and from people who succeeded in scaling some elements' width while keeping some constant spaces between them.

[image: representation of my problem with a schema]

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: The gap property solved the issue. In fact, I tried to create a component which encapsulated a flex component. It didn't work. I switched by using a grid as parent component, then I set a gap between each child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to implement this would be through CSS Grid where you will get access to a css property

```
gap: 10px; /* 10px is just an example*/
```

This will give you more control of your layout and give consistent spaces which makes it more responsive.

You can learn about CSS Grid through:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot, that actually solved my problem, the gap property allowed for a perfect responsive. I really appreciate the help, have a great day!

Comment: Glad I could help, Happy Coding!